# Facet not working Variants product price but on Base product price

Tags: sorting, solr, sap-commerce-cloud, faceted-search

We have the following set up in Hybris:

Base Product with Price Row

```
   |________Variant Product with respective Price Rows
```

Currently we are just indexing the base products with their respective rice rows.When the user lands on PLP the Price facets are displayed based upon the Base Product price even though the PLP has the variants displayed.

Is there a configuration in Hybris which we can leverage to display the facets based upon the variant prices.The number of variants for each product is quite high hence we can not index the variants products.

Comment: In most Hybris Projects the information shown on the PLP page is not taken from SOLR(not from Facets). It is displayed Directly from DB(fetched to data objects and so On). From what I understand the right price for variants is not used. Do the Variants have a price set on tehm ? Check the JSPs or tags to see why the Base Product Price is being shown instead of Variants Product prices

Comment: The variants do have the price rows.The facets are not displaying the price ranges based upon the variants ,its displaying the facets based upon the base prices.Say the price for base is £100 and that of the variant is £400 and there is just 1 variant product being displayed on PLP ,the facet shows £100 and not £400

Comment: You said you only index the base products. Then how come that variants are shown on the product list page?